# Why :host-context is required when :host can suffice the needs in Angular

Tags: css, angular

As I understand `:host-context` is used to apply styles based on selector of parent.

Lets consider a rule as follows:

`:host-context(.red-theme) { background-color: red; }`

same can be written using :host selector as folows:

`.red-theme :host { background-color: red; }`

Then whh is `host-context` explicitly required?

Comment: demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z3xxtu

Comment: Since `:host-context` is not supported in many browsers I am trying to use the alternative way using just `:host` but I can't seem to get the same behaviour

Answer (score 2):

Use `:host` if you want to style the component custom HTML element itself.

Where as `:host-context` is used when you also want to have a component apply a style taking into account context in which component is rendered.

So for example, you could do: (with `host-context`)

```
<div class="red-theme">
    <app-component></app-component>
</div>
```

where `app-component`

```
<button class="btn btn-theme">Button</button>
```

and the component style is defined:

```
:host-context(.red-theme) .btn-theme {
    background: red;
 }
```

Useful if you want to have multiple alternative themes on your web application.

Comment: `Where as :host-context is used when you also want to have a component apply a style to some element outside of it.` is wrong you probably meant `Where as :host-context is used when you also want to have a component apply a style taking into account context in which component is rendered.`

Comment: @penleychan Your answer explains the use of :host-context. But the question is - the same thing can be done with just :host as well, then what extra does :host-context do?

Comment: @NoelSchenk No idea, not part of the angular team. Here's a link if you wanna learn more about these `:host`, `:host-context` https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/

Answer (score 1):

`:host` and `:host-context` are **not** Angular features, but CSS features.

Within the demo provided at [stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z3xxtu](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z3xxtu), the Angular components are merged into the DOM and allow plain old CSS selector structure like `.parent :host .child { color: red; }`.

This changes when using Webcomponents and ShadowDOM.

The ShadowDOM acts as a barrier and encapsulates the contained markup and style, so the `.parent` cannot style the things on the `:host` and vice versa. Note *cannot* is not *totally* true, see `::part` and `CSS Custom Properties`.

With a structure like `<parent> <my-component> ShadowDOM <child>` the above CSS rule no longer works and `:host-context(.parent)` (which could be read as `.parent :host`) is needed. Sadly as of 2023-01-10 [this doesn't work in Firefox and Safari](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host-context#browser_compatibility).

In the above demo, `:host-context(.red) { color: red; }` and `.red :host { color: red; }` produce the same output *because there's no ShadowDOM involved*. On top of that, Angular transforms the *invalid* `.test :host` in the CSS to `.test [_nghost-some-id]` which is a *valid* CSS selector.